# bootstrap grid offset left

Tags: css, alignment

I have a simple bootstrap layout.
I need to create space between the cols, therefore I have used some offset classes. There is only one challange. I need the first row, to be at the left (without space to the left), and the second col in middle of the first and last, so they will all be aligned nicely.

How is that possible in bootstrap? I have tried using the offset system, but I can't seem to get it working.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<div class="row posts">
      <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-1 post">
        <span class="post-title block">headline col 1</span>
        <span class="post-content block">content</span>
        <a class="read-more block" href="">Read more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-1 post">
        <span class="post-title block">headline col 2</span>
        <span class="post-content block">content</span>
        <a class="read-more block" href="">Read more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-1 post">
        <span class="post-title block">headline col 3</span>
        <span class="post-content block">content</span>
        <a class="read-more block" href="">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Check this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7a8tz591/

The above is giving following result, I would like it as explained here:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using boostrap flex box it's possible:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row posts  d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-lg-3 post">
      <span class="post-title block">headline col 1</span>
      <span class="post-content block">content</span>
      <a class="read-more block" href="">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 post">
      <span class="post-title block">headline col 2</span>
      <span class="post-content block">content</span>
      <a class="read-more block" href="">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 post">
      <span class="post-title block">headline col 3</span>
      <span class="post-content block">content</span>
      <a class="read-more block" href="">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I removed the class `offset-lg-1` from each of the div blocks.

Comment: So simple, so beautiful. Thank you :-)